# Why there are many commits messages in PR

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

Why there are many commits messages in my PR?

I am following this way,

I am on main branch then create new branch

1 - `git checkout -b feature-abc main`

after development finished (with some commit to local branch)

2 - `git checkout main`

3 - `git pull origin main`

4 - `git checkout -`

5 - `git merge --no-ff main`

add some messages and resolve conflict

6 - `git push origin feature-abc`

Please below screenshot, I just want to see only the last commit on this PR. How do I do this without any issue?(code missing)
[image: Click to see my PR Commit]

Comment: Is your project using regular merges, rebasing, or squash merges for merging on GitHub?

Comment: @bk2204 I am using regular merge (`git merge --no-ff main`). I tried `git rebase main`. I lost some code

Answer (score 0):

A Pull Request is a Github feature that allow Request a branch merge action to another branch.this history of commits are the history of commits performed in that branch.

Comment: This answer, while perhaps seeming somewhat tautological, does in fact seem to be the correct point to make. You say "after development finished (with some commit to local branch)". Okay, so unless you do something about it, all those "some commits to local branch" will be part of the pull request, because that is what a pull request is: it's a merge of a branch, performed at the server side, and your branch has "some commits" so they are all part of the history that is getting merged. Your use of reverse merge reduces the risk of _conflict_ during fwd merge but it doesn't shorten history.

Comment: @matt do you know remove unnecessary commit on PR?

Comment: There are lots of ways to rewrite commit history. You can easily squash a whole branch down to one commit, for example. But I do not know what you mean by unnecessary. It’s unclear what your goal is, and anyway that is not want you asked.

Comment: @matt Thank you for your help.. check my own answer

Answer (score 0):

I remove my local main branch

`git branch -D main`

Then fetch from remote

`git fetch`

Then create a new branch from the main

`git checkout -b new-branch main`

After development is done, I again checkout main and pull (ff only)

`git pull origin --ff-only main`

Then checkout to my dev branch and merge with main (with ff only)

`git merge --ff-only main`

Final Result

[image: final result look like this]